# How can I make it so the last div does not flow into the next line on hover?

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so that the div with the id #watching-margin does not get pushed over into the next line of divs when I hover on the 11th div. Instead, I'd like it so that it would just move to the right without interruption, and possibly just hiding part of the id #watching-margin to keep the flow nice. Thank you!

```css
#section{
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:2px;
}

.watching{
  position:relative;
  width:12%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:250px;
  background-color:red;
}

.watching img{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

.watching{
  margin-left:-50px;
  transition:.3s ease;
}

.watching:hover{
  margin-right:50px;
  transition:.3s ease;
}

#watching-margin{
  margin-left:-50px;
}

#watching-margin:hover{
  margin-right:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id=section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching" id="watching-margin">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="watching">
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to switch to `inline-block` element instead of float and use `white-space:nowrap` on container so that you keep them always in the same line:

```css
#section {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.watching {
  position: relative;
  width: 12%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size:initial;
}

.watching img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.watching {
  margin-left: -50px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.watching:hover {
  margin-right: 50px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

#watching-margin {
  margin-left: -50px;
}

#watching-margin:hover {
  margin-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
  <section id=section>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching" id="watching-margin">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>
      <div class="watching">
        <div class=img></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>
```